# Return a collection of type class for a method returning a collection of interface

Tags: c#

I have a interface, `ISensor` that has a method that returns a list of an interface type `ISensorMeasurement`. I then implement `ISensor` and want to know if there is a way to return a collection that implements `ISensorMeasurement`.

For example, the `SensorModel.GetMeasurementsInRange<TemperatureMeasurement>` Method returns a `List<TemperatureMeasurement>`. `TemperatureMeasurement` Implements `ISensorMeasurement`, but the compiler doesn't like me returning this type.

I have trimmed down the interface and class to a minimum for the sake of simplicity.

```
public interface ISensor
{
    int Id { get; set; }

    List<ISensorMeasurement> GetRangeOfMeasurements(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate);
}

public class TemperatureSensor : ISensor
{
    public int Id { get ;; }
    private SensorModel SensorModel { get; set; } = new SensorModel();

    public List<ISensorMeasurement> GetRangeOfMeasurements(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        return SensorModel.GetMeasurementsInRange<TemperatureMeasurement>(Id, startDate, endDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to convert your list to one of the interface, which you can do by returning `yourList.Cast<ISensorMeasurement>().ToList()`.

Comment: `List<T>` is not covariant (classes in C# do not support covariance/contravariance; only interfaces do). Try returning covariant interface `IEnumerable<ISensorMeasurement>`.